# how to insert an angular 1.5 component with ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, components

I have a component, and i would like to inject it dynamically into my html.

I have a component like this:

```
angular.module('test1', []);

angular.module('test1').component('test1', {
    templateUrl: 'components/test1/test1.template.html',
    controller: function test1Controller($scope) {
    }
});
```

the `test1.template.html` file looks like this:

```
<p>TEST 1</p>
```

on my controller i have this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ctrlCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.tag = "<test1/>";
  });
```

on my `index.html`, i have this:

```
<ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="tag"></ng-bind-html>
```

but the tag will not show up. I have tried writing literaly `"'<p>hi!</p>'"` on the `ng-bind-html` field, and the text "hi!" shows up on a paragraph, so i don't think this error is because of a typo.

I also tried to use `$sce.trustAsHtml`, but it didn't work neither :(

```
$scope.tag = $sce.trustAsHtml("<test1/>");
```

when i insert an input field, the trustAsHtml method does work, but when i try to inject my components dynamically, it just won't let me, please help D:

Comment: `ng-bind-html` doesn't compile directives. Why such a roundabout way of doing this?

Comment: really? aww man, that's terrible!... I have a library of components, the user will be able to drag this components to a place, in order to create a layout with all this components combined. Basicallly, I want to create the component dynamically to achieve this :(

Comment: not hard to use `$compile` and compile them yourself

Comment: Tutorial on using $compile http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx

Answer (score 2):

### Why `ng-include` won't work?

Components need to be **compiled** before you can use them on the markup. Try editing the html of the app with the developer tools from your browser, by artificially injecting your component on the markup: it won't work.

### How to dynamically include components?

you'll need to use directives, this [tutorial](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx) (thanks to @Artem K.) is friendly to follow, but you can also read the [angular's official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), it is a little hard to understand though.

Following the logic of the final example of the angular's official documentation, you can create a directive that compiles everything that is passed to it, like this:

```
// source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('my-compile', function ($compile) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
          // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
          return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
          // when the 'compile' expression changes
          // assign it into the current DOM
          element.html(value);

          // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
          // scope.
          // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
          // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
      );
    };
  });
```

and then, on your `index.html`, you'll have to invoke the directive, sending the the string containing the component's tag as an argument.

```
<div compile="tag"></div>
```

As @charlietfl and @Artem K. said, you have to understand the angular's `$compile` so, thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Thank you so much! After 3 days stuck on this, your answer did the trick.